# How does Spring Security redirect a user who is unauthenticated to an external login page (AWS Cognito)?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, amazon-cognito

I have developed a basic Spring boot service with Spring security with the following config

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          cognito:
            clientId: yyyy
            clientSecret: xxxx
            scope: openid
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/cognito
            clientName: spring-sso
        provider:
          cognito:
            issuerUri: https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/zzzzzzzzzz
            user-name-attribute: cognito:username
```

It all works fine, the user is redirected to AWS Cognito SSO page.

However I can't pinpoint where the logic for this redirect happens in Spring framework.

I enabled debug and can see a list of Security Filters that are called in the chain.

```
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter
  OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter
  DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter
  DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
```

I placed debug points on `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter`, `DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter` and `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` but no success.

Where does the magic happen where it constructs the URL to send the user to SSO page:

> If non authenticated user accessing secure page --> then redirect to SSO login page

The reason I am interested, is so I can determine if I can use the same library in an old Jakarta EE application or not.

Answer (score 1):

The interface responsible for redirecting an unauthenticated user in Spring Security is called `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. (I always found the name confusing, but the idea is that it's telling an unauthenticated user where to authenticate, i.e. find the "entry".)

As for the filter, look in the `ExceptionTranslationFilter`.

In the version that I'm currently looking at (5.3.4) it's in `doFilter` then `handleSpringSecurityException` then `sendStartAuthentication`, here `authenticationEntryPoint.commence` is called.

Comment: Thanks, when debugging it generates a redirect-uri of `/oauth2/authorization/cognito` not an AWS cognito URL. So is that happening somewhere else downstream?

Comment: So it appears that the actual redirect happens at Line 218 of **OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter** when servlet path of `/oauth2/authorization/cognito` is used